# Row number does not update as I drag it down using INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I try to get a sum of a range across different sheets the row does not update as I drag down my formula. In B1 I have the name of the sheet, which I am using as reference. As I drag across it updates to C1,D1 etc., but the rows as I mentioned do not update as I drag down.
I tried with this formula:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!B2:AF2"))`

, but when I drag it down the rows do not update and I get the total for the same range B2:AF2 and I want it to be B3:AF3, I tried this as well:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!B"& ROW()))`

and the row seems to be updating, however I am not getting the sum of the range B2:AF2, but I am getting only the value from B2,B3,B4 etc.
If anyone could help It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"'"&B$1&"'!B"& ROW()&":AF"&Row())`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That solved my problem :)